# Is there an API for websites to disable ad block plus themselves?

Tags: google-chrome, web, adblock

I am using the Ad Block Plus extension in Chrome 115 and something caught my attention from a developer's perspective.

On https://satellites.pro/ I got a popup to disable the Ad Block to support the website, which is fine.

I click the button and the Ad blocker get's disabled directly (I did not have to navigate to the Ad blocker and disable it manually).

How is this working from a technical perspective? Couldn't a website trigger this automatically and just disable the ad blocker without asking me? Is this using some Ad Block Plus API?

Entering the website the first time - Remark: "Anzeigen zulassen" is German and says "Accept ads".

[image: Popup to disable adds, ABP is on]

After clicking the button (1)

[image: Website reloaded after clicking the button, ABP is off]

Comment: Oh that sounds like a security hazard

Comment: I found this: https://gitlab.com/eyeo/adblockplus/abc/webext-sdk/-/issues/171

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this in the Javascript code of the website:

```
c.initCustomEvent("domain_allowlisting_request", !0, !0, b);
```

Which lead me to https://gitlab.com/eyeo/adblockplus/abc/webext-sdk/-/merge_requests/298

So, yes, there seems to be an API for websites to unblock themselves.

There is more concept in https://gitlab.com/eyeo/adblockplus/abc/webext-sdk/-/issues/171 and it looks like this should only work for "trusted sites".

Comment: Any news on this? Visited satellites.pro with ABP Chrome Canary and did not saw the message. Did you find out what these event parameters are?